# onSubmit makes unwanted url change

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS. I have a form, and "onSubmit" of that form I want to get the contents of the form and then redirect to another page. This sort of works except this changes my url which I don't want. What I want it to redirect to is:

localhost:3000/somewebsite

but instead it becomes:

localhost:3000/somewebsite?input-form1=hello&input-form2=hi

This is what my code looks like:

```
<form onSubmit={this.urlSubmit} action="/somewebsite">
  <input name="input-form1" placeholder="Enter URL" />
  <Form.Control name="input-form2" as="select" placeholder="Select language">
    <option value="XX">Select Language</option>
  </Form.Control>
  <button className="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please add **event** as param of urlSubmit method and add `event.preventDefault();` as part of that method to avoid refresh/URL change effect on form submit.

& You don't need `action="/somewebsite"` as part of form

```
urlSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // rest of your code goes here...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would this allow the page to redirect to "/somewebsite" (which is a new page)?

Comment: Yes, but you will have to redirect manually from within that method like this
this.props.history.push('/somewebsite');